# UITableViewController within UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to load a specific `UITableViewController` as the Detail view of a `UISplitViewController` when the user selects a cell within the Master view; but having some problems. When i select the cell, it just shows a blank window with out a table view controller.

However if i change the App Delegate to just load the `UITableView` controller without using the `UISplitViewController` it works fine, so i know it's a problem with the way i've coded the `UISplitViewController.`

**The view hierachy:**

```
UISplitViewController 
--> 
    UINavigationController 
    --> UITableViewController (DetailViewController)

    UINavigationController
    --> UIViewController (ColorViewController)
```

The user selects a cell in `ColorViewController` and that should change the `DetailViewController.`

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = [self.viewController splitViewController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}
```

In `ViewController.m`:

```
- (UIViewController *) splitViewController {

// Create the navigation-run root view
ColorViewController *rootVC = [ColorViewController controller];

UINavigationController *rootNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];

// Create the navigation-run detail view
DetailViewController *detailVC = [DetailViewController controller];

UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

// Add both to the split view controller
svc = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

svc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: rootNav, detailNav, nil];

svc.delegate = detailVC;

return svc;

}
```

In `ColorViewController.m`:

```
@interface ColorViewController : UITableViewController

...    

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)self.splitViewController.delegate;

TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

[controller.view addSubview:tvc.view];

}
```

What's the best way to change the Detail view within a `UISplitViewController`? Should i just add the replacement view to `UIViewController` like above or is there a better way? Maybe that's the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question..

For some reason, in the Master view (ColorViewController), the detail object `TableViewController *tvc` needs to be declared as an instance variable, not as a variable within a method.

After doing that, it works and displays the table properly.

I don't really understand why though, if anyone would like to try to explain.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a navigation controller handling the detail side of your split view, your strategy should be to use it to push your new table view controller.  When I've done this, I've kept references to both navigation controllers as properties in the app delegate so that I can use one or the other for push operations.

I'm not sure what the real purpose of your `ViewController` class is but if you move its `splitViewController` method into the app delegate it would be easier to change the navigation controllers from local variables to properties in a place where they can be easily accessed.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try doing that. I think it might help to solve the problem.